# Error while opening workbook in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio

Here is c# code:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
string workbookPath = "c:/users/user/desktop/1200patients/pharmgkb/drugs.xls";
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

I get the following error on the last line:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
ErrorCode: -2146827284
```

I think I may have specified the arguments wrong. I went to the documentation and I can't put my finger on what is specified incorrectly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: a */* is seen (usually) as an escape character. if you wanted to display one on screen, you would have to use **//**. in this case, however, DavidG has the answer by using backslash's instead

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am still getting the same error with the new path though?

Comment: at what point do you use the **newWorkbook**?

Comment: the next line is:  Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

Comment: I'm not experienced in this, but try adding **new** after **Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook =**

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong - the slashes are forward instead of backslashes. Try this (and note the `@` prefix that denotes a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)):

```
string workbookPath = @"c:\users\user\desktop\1200patients\pharmgkb\drugs.xls";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still getting the error even with that path though. That said, why is the @ symbol there? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try with a simple `Open(workbookPath);` and I'll update the answer.

Comment: This may sound crazy but can you create a folder called `Desktop` in here `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\` and try again?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want me to make the Desktop folder and then copy the rest of the folders (1200patients...) into the new Desktop folder or should I leave the Desktop folder empty?

Comment: No, just create that folder, nothing else.

Comment: Oh, would it make a difference if my microsoft excel is not activated?

Comment: Possibly, activate it and see what happens.

Comment: Hi David, I activated office but still getting an error. Then I tried Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = new Excel.Workbook(), I am now getting a different error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: Is this a web project?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update this with the answer. I solved this by creating the file in excel and choosing the xlsx file extension. Originally, I had created the file in open office and it had an xls file extension. Apparently, an xls file extension does not work with the interop library?

Comment: .xls file extensions certainly do work with interop.  Interop was around way before .xlsx extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In my System is installed Office 2010

in your references must have, office Office Interop 14

Also check the Task Manager, sometimes the error may be due to many instances of Excel left open

[image]

try this

```
   String fileTest ="c:/users/user/desktop/1200patients/pharmgkb/drugs.xls";

   Excel.Application xlApp;
   Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
   Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
   object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

   xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   xlApp.Visible = false;
   xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
   xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@fileTest, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
   xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```